# Not enough permission to change Bug Workflow

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am using TFS Service (on the cloud solution) and I would like to customize the bug states.
There are many resources explaining how to do that using TFS Power Tools, so I downloaded and installed it.
I am able to open the workflow, but I am not able to change anything because I get the following error message:

> Failed to save the 'Bug' Work Item Type to the server. TF237113: You
>   don't have enough permission to complete the import operation

I am using an administrator user.

Is it possible to make this change on Visual Studio Online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are correct that it is not possible to customise the process template on Visual Studio Online you do have a few options:

1. Kanban Columns - If you want to you can [customise the Kanban columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj838789%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so that you have 'meta states' that you can use. I know that it is not the same but it could get you there.
2. Go offline - Currently and for a limited time you can take your [VSO account on-premises](http://blogs.objectsharp.com/post/2014/04/08/Visual-Studio-Online-Data-Export.aspx). The TFS team are holding the version of VSO in parity with TFS 2013 Update 2 so that folks can do this. Be aware of what you loose though. No frequent updates and you have to host your own servers...

Not sure if these options help but they are options...

Comment: Sorry I took so long to notice your answer, I will bring these options back to my team :)

Answer (score 2):

Making more research I found the answer: it is not possible:
http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3654231-customize-process-template-on-visual-studio-online